# built-in speakers not working when a HDMI display is connected

Tags: sound, hdmi, output

I have an external display connected through HDMI and headphones connected via jack to my laptop with Ubuntu installed.
With this config I go into Settings, audio and select `speaker-sof-hda-dsp` as output device. However, I no sound is coming through the built-in speakers. If I select the other output devices available, everything works fine. Also, if I disconnect the the HDMI, sound does come out from the speakers.

Does anyone know how to fix this "misbehaviour"?